Code metrics in Visual Studio Code for .NET?
I am trying to generate a code metrics for a .NET application I cloned from Github. Is there any way to do this in Visual Studio Code ?
Or can this only be done with Visual Studio? I am using Mac and I have been using Visual Studio Code for pretty much everything I do

Configure the C# Extension to enable Metrics, then open a file and "Calculate Code Metrics" or "Show Code Metrics"

what extension should I use for vscode that works with c# ?

"C# for Visual Studio Code" extension published by Microsoft
